# Is it good practice to create new tables for new elements in a database?

Tags: database-design, best-practices

I am trying to create a good model for a database that I need for an application. The way that I have tought about realizing it involves creating a new table for each new element that is added, but I am unsure if that really is such a good idea. I found a related question that used a garden as an analogy, and I quite liked that, so I will try to exemplify using that below. Note that each gardener only works with one garden. The gardeners doesn't need to be able to be at several gardens.

I have a set of **Gardereners** as such:

```
PrimaryKey | Name | Garden
1          | Bob  | Garden1
2          | James| Garden2
3          | Ian  | Garden3
```

Each **Garden** will point to a new table containing the flowers. The **Garden** contains all the flowers in that garden.

```
FlowerNumber | Type
1            | Holly
2            | Lilach
3            | Larch
```

The question is then, would it be "right" to create a new table **Garden** for each new **Gardener** that is created? I tought it kind of wasteful to create new tables all the time, but I am not sure of any other ways to do it. I think object-oriented thinking might have perverted my way of thinking about databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. This will cause maintenance problems: when you want to update the structure of `Garden`, then changes (adding a new column, removing an old column, changes to constraints, changes to triggers, whatever) will have to be propagated to every `Garden_*` table. It is also bad data modelling. You should aim to have one table per entity/relation in your system. Having multiple `Garden` tables would imply that they are fundamentally different.

I'd suggest a structure more like this:

```
Gardener
--------
  ID (PK)
  Garden_ID (FK to Garden.ID)
  (other fields such as name, contact info, ...)

Garden
------
  ID (PK)
  (other fields such as name, garden address, ...)

Flower
------
  ID (PK)
  Type_ID (FK to FlowerTypes.ID)
  Garden_ID (FK to Garden.ID)
  (other fields)

FlowerType
----------
  ID (PK)
  name
  (other fields)
```

The data for this schema could look like this:

```
Gardner
-------
ID | Name  | Garden_ID
-----------|----------
1  | Bob   | 100
2  | Sally | 101


Garden
------
ID | Name
---------
100| Big garden
101| Little garden


Flower
------
ID  |  Type_ID  | Garden_ID
----|-----------|----------
1   |  200      |  100
2   |  201      |  100
3   |  202      |  101

Flower_type
-----------
ID   | Name
-----------
200  | Lilly
201  | Hosta
202  | Rose
```

This will let a gardener be assigned to *one* garden. If you need more flexibility such that gardeners can be assigned to multiple gardens, and gardens can have multiple gardeners assigned to them, you'd need a separate garden assignment table, and remove the `garden_id` field from `gardener`:

```
garden_assignments
------------------
  ID (PK)
  garden_ID (FK to garden.ID)
  gardener_ID (FK to gardener.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

No I think there is no such need.
You just create a new table **Garden** which will have its own primary key & it should contain foreign key of the **Gardner**. So that you can maintain the relationship between these tables & can fetch data using SQL. Be aware about inserting & deleting data with foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your model above works for a list of flowers where the garden is not relevant. But it wouldn't work when flowers or gardeners could be in multiple gardens.

You should have a table for each type of entity. You don't have a garden table, you have a flower table, so to complete the model you need to add a **Garden** table and link **Flower** table to it.

Eg.

```
GardenerID | Name   | Garden
1          | Bob    | 1
2          | James  | 2
3          | Ian    | 3

FlowerID   | Type   | Garden
1          | Holly  | 1
2          | Lilach | 2
3          | Larch  | 3
4          | Larch  | 2

GardenID   | Address
1          | 221b Baker St
2          | 29 Acacia Rd
3          | 10 Downing St
```

Of course where the foreign keys are depends on how you want to define the relationships and whether you want multiple gardeners to a garden or vice versa.

Comment: I have updated the original question slightly to clarify further. I am assuming that each gardener will only be working in one garden, and does not move around. The Garden table lists everything that is in that garden.